# How to plot a line inside a "While" loop in python?

Tags: python, loops, matplotlib

Trying to plot a line inside a "while" loop using matplotlib.
This shows a blank figure:

```
plt.plot(t, cash)
plt.xlim([t_start, t_end])
plt.ylim([c_min,c_max])
plt.pause(0.1)
```

then using:

```
plt.plot(t, cash,'r.')
plt.xlim([t_start, t_end])
plt.ylim([c_min,c_max])
plt.pause(0.1)
```

shows red dots being updated with the while loop, as expected.
How to get this plot with a line?
Thank You !

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "How to get this plot with a line?" In your own words, where the code says `plt.plot(t, cash,'r.')`, what does the `'r.'` part signify? If you do not know, please try to read the documentation in order to understand. You should also immediately see how to change it, in order to get a line plot instead.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand the problem, but it sounds like you simply want to exchange the dot with a line plot?

```
plt.plot(t, cash,'r-')
```